# Stretching a horizontal linearLayout content to full width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an issue to stretch the content of in a horizontal linear layout to the full width. It seems like a trivial issue, but I am not super experienced in Android. I tried several solutions, but nothing did the trick.

I want to create a table with a fixed header, that I use as a fragment. The main structure of it looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tableContentHorizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">
                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </TableLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.widget.HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Besides that I have 2 layouts that define the cells of the table. The layout of the header cells looks like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerCellTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12345679" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

... and the cell layout for the content looks that:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:minWidth="150dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contentCellTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="1234567910101010" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCb41.png)

The number of columns can vary and if the columns don't fill the full width of a screen, like in this case, then the columns should be stretched equally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting your cells `android:maxWidth="150dp"` so that's as wide as it gets. Try setting the width to 0dp with a weight of 1 to allow it to fill out equally.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

**EDIT:**
[image: 1]]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tableContentHorizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerCellTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="12" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerCellTextView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="12" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerCellTextView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="12" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/contentCellTextView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:maxWidth="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:text="0101010" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/contentCellTextView2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:maxWidth="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:text="12" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/contentCellTextView3"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:maxWidth="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:text="10" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.widget.HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are right, maxWidth doesn't make sense. I was just concentrating so much on the table header part, that I forgot to remove it. I also played around with weight, but I couldn't get it to work. So I already tried what you suggest.

Comment: I don't like all the nested layouts but something like that should get you an equal distribution of the cells.

Comment: Weird, it wasn't working the first time I tried it. Ohh well, I certainly overlooked something. Now it is working! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way but you can always do math.

Get the screen width with getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels and divide by the number of columns. Get the result and set the cell width.

Comment: I figured, that I have to go this route eventually. Probably the best way I guess. Not sure if I tried the snippet you posted, but in the past I didn't had the best experience to grab the exact screen size of a device. Maybe that changed with newer Android vers., but unfortunately I have still to use 5.1. But I will check it out, thanks.